# gitlab unable to access 'mygitlab.addr' failed connect to 'mygitlab.addr' Protocol not available

Tags: git, gitlab

I created three virtual machines ，A, B, C.
The three virtual machine networks are connected to each other ,can ping pong

In A , I created a GitLab private server by docker.
I can pull and push in IDEA

But In B, I want to `git clone` from A's gitlab server, and the SSH key is generated， I have put the public key on the gitlab server.

And I configured user Name and user.email.

[image: git clone]

Comment: "Protocol not available" is an unusual error. It *can* be caused by an incorrect docker setup. See, e.g., [this openSSL related item](https://github.com/jonathonmcmurray/reQ/issues/18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you use an SSH key, you should use an SSH URL

```
git clone git@192.168.56.100:<user>/java_project.git
```

Second, this assumes:

- GitLab is on 192.168.56.100 the A machine
- GitLab manages (hosts) the java_project.git created under the GitLab user account
- GitLab user account SSH setting has the public key from the key pair created on B (which is hopefully what you mean by "I have put the public key on the gitlab server", because adding the public key directly on the A `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` would not work)

You can test from B your SSH connection to GitLab A server with:

```
ssh -Tv git@192.168.56.100
```

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJT56.png

Comment: @BugMaker Check your sshd_config and sshd service state on A: SSH daemon needs to be running for your SSH queries to be listened to.